# Elegant way to deal UILabel text alignment ?

Tags: ios, uilabel, uitextview, text-alignment

I'm developing an app in iOS 6 and using Xcode 4.5.2.

I have a simple **UIView** which contains some text according to localizable string. Well, according to displayed language, the number of lines of the text is changing.For exemple, in English, there is two lines, but in Turkish, it takes just one line.

I'm also supposed to center text alignment. Well, right now i'm able to accomplish it, but i'm using two different **UILabel** and i've set their text manually. So, it doesn't work if i change the displayed language of the text [image: Simple image]

So,

**1-** What is the best way to handle this kind of alignment issue ?

**2-** Suppose that i use `UILabel`, well how can i make a new line to be able to have the output as shown in the pic. None of the line breaking mode seems to work. Same question if i use `UITextView`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what about using  multiline label?

Comment: @AKV, nope it doesn't work, because it doesn't predict when to pass a new line.

Comment: what is it about an `UIWebView` with localised `HTML` content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do these thing

1. Set your number of line to 0.
2. Make your text alignment centre.
3. Insert **`\n`** character in you string where you want line break.
4. Make sure to set the width of your `UILabel`.

By default when text reaches the width of the lablel it moves to next line but what you want that before it reaches to it's width it should move to next line which is not possible by setting the properties of `UILabel`. For that you have to set new line character in your string.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `UILabel` Instance method [`textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006797-CH3-SW11)

From the documentation:

> The value 0 indicates there is no maximum number of lines and that the
>   rectangle should encompass all of the text.

Comment: How can i tell UILabel to pass a new line ?

Comment: [myLabel setNumberOfLines:0];

Comment: Right now, if you dragged a label to your view in the storyboard, it's most likely set to 1.